# Android google map in full screen using immersion

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working in an android app, and I will like to have an interface like Uber with the map in full screen but I can't get the result as I want.

Comment: Please show your code. Otherwise it's hard to know what you have that is not working

Comment: Generally, you have [Immersive Activity Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html), and a SupportMapFragment that occupies the whole Activity